# How to set the language of a doc to a DB field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to set the language of a document body to a value fetch from the DB in SSRS? I tried with a simple expression and I got this error. I wonder what the best workaround is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a work around for you.

1. Set up a new dataset to pull back the language value (let's say language_dataset into column language_value).
2. Create a parameter, let's say called language.  Set it to internal and set its default value -> Get values from a query and use the dataset and value you just set up.
3. In the Report properties, Language -> expression and set the expression to `=Parameters!language.Value`.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: It also worked by getting the value in the application that calls the report, a web app in my case, and then passing the value as a parameter to the report.